# Append operator "<<" no longer converting AssociationRelation to Arrays and adding object automatically on Rails 5 after migrating from Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently inherited and updated a very extensive Rails 4 app. Everything seems to be working fine except I'm noticing these issues on a few areas (testing not automated on those special cases unfortunately).

From another part of the app:

```
_otherstuff = Thing.where("color = orange")
_otherstuff_ids = _otherstuff.collect &:id
```

Problematic code:

```
things = Thing.where("color = red")       
things.each do |thing|
  if !_otherstuff_ids.include?(thing.id)
      _otherstuff << thing # Rails 5 is not happy with this anymore?
  end
end
```

Obviously if I convert _otherstuff.to_a, then the problem is gone. But my question is why is this a problem now with Rails 5 and it wasn't a problem with Rails 4. It looks like Rails 4 was automatically converting an AssociationRelation to an Array and then pushing the new object into it. In the documentation of Rails, this operation apparently adds the new object to the association setting the foreign keys, which wasn't the case in this case.. the app has come to expect this behavior in a few areas. What changed and what should I be aware of now?

Comment: `_otherstuff << stuff` why push stuff back into `_otherstuff` when it is already in the collection? Also modifying a collection of any kind inside a loop is not a great idea

Comment: I fixed the question sample code, had a "bug"; was something quick to just show the kind of code that was causing that. And yes, I agree with you @engineersmnky, this kind of loop sucks for this particular case; so all that will be refactored soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like rails 5 not supports << anymore for AR relation, because the array that stores records will be frozen

You can see more in the [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25906)

Comment: That's a great find; it's amazing how this is not mentioned anywhere, not any of the most popular "Rails" upgrade guides out there mentions this, which, to me could be a potentially dangerous breaking incompatibility; and it sucks we found this bug after a production deployment. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Could you please accept an answer if it helped?